# In Unix "less", can I jump to the next line that does NOT contain X?

Tags: unix, grep, less

In the Unix `less` tool, is it possible to jump to the next line that does *not* contain a certain expression?

I sometimes have to look through files that contain thousands of similar adjacent lines that, for example, all say "Computing *something*" and I'm interested in the next line after the current block, which does not contain the word "Computing".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, this is non-match search functionality, for example:

`less file.conf`

then you type `/` and after that `!` your last line should look like:

```
Non-match /
```

then type your pattern for example `Non-match /^#` to look for first line without beginning `#`

Instead of `!` character you can also use `Ctrl+N`.

Comment: This is perfect. Couldn't have expected a better answer.

Comment: For the backward non-matching search type `?!pattern`. To repeat the previous search type `/!` + `Enter` or `?!` + `Enter`.

Answer (score 5):

As an addition to Casual Coder's answer:

You could also filter out the lines altogether:

```
<logfile grep -v mypattern |less
```

The disadvantage is that you have to quit and restart grep to change the pattern; the advantage is that the lines you don't want to see are hidden, which makes it easier to spot interesting patterns in the lines that you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Not only can you jump between lines that don't contain X, you can hide the lines that do contain X, using `less`'s `&` regex filter command.

```
less file.conf
```

then type `&!^Computing`then the `enter` key and all those line will be hidden from view.

You can still search within the remaining lines with `/`.

Once you find the line you want you can bring the others back if you need their context - type `&` then the `enter` key to remove the filter.